# ¿Cómo manejar una variable en diferentes pantallas?

Tags: java, netbeans, java-swing, lista, jframe

He tenido este problema, estoy comenzando a hacer mi primer proyecto con GUI, en netbeans, no se como manejar una variable que se lee de un campo del programa en ejecución, y poder verificarla o mostrarla en otra jframe u otra pantalla, y que esta conserve lo mismo asignado, ¿hay algún método de "declararla", tal un programa de consola?, como por ejemplo un array de usuarios, que guarde id y pass, y que pueda pasarla a otra jframe o que pueda ser consultado sus valores por otra pantalla es decir lo que busco es sincronía entre jframe en cuanto a variables creadas, o mejor dicho una variable que sea global.

Sus respuesta serian de gran ayuda.

nota: sean explícitos en sus respuestas, (beginner).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

puedes usar `static`

Una variable, clase, funcion cuando es declarado como estático puede ser invocado sin la necesidad de tener que instanciar un objeto de la clase.

```
public class ejemploMath {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double varMath = Math.pow(2,10);
    }
}
```

en tu caso lo puedes emplear de la siguiente manera:

```
public class EjemploEstatico {
static int variableEntera=104;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double varMath = Math.pow(2,10);
    }
}
```

Como accedo a la variable `int VariableEnteraCopia` con su valor actual?

para responder esa pregunta creamos otra clase y la invocamos simplemente(sin instanciar la Clase)

```
public class EjemploInvocacion {
int VariableEnteraCopia;
public ejemploInvocacion(){
VariableEnteraCopia=EjemploEstatico.variableEntera;
System.out.println(VariableEnteraCopia);//deberia imprimir 104
}
}
```

Hagamos enfasis en: la clase `EjemploEstatico` no es instanciada en la clase `EjemploInvocacion`, y de ese modo accedemos a su atributo en el estado actual `EjemploEstatico.variableEntera`

Comment: Gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder, me haz ayudado en mi trabajo. :D

Comment: Estoy tratando de programar como comentaste, ojalá no tenga trabas en el camino.

Comment: Listo :) Gracia nuevamente.